Which versions of @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor are compatible with which versions of Cypress?
Which version of @badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor can I use with Cypress 13? Is it even compatible? I'm getting type issues in my cypress.config.ts file:
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';
import { addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin } from '@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor';
import createBundler from '@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor';
import { createEsbuildPlugin } from '@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild';

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/',
    screenshotOnRunFailure: true,
    specPattern: 'cypress/**/*.feature',
    video: false,
    viewportHeight: 660,
    viewportWidth: 1000,
    async setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

      on(
        'file:preprocessor',
        createBundler({
          plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin(config)], //ERROR ON THIS LINE!
        }),
      );

      return config;
    },
  },
});


The error is long, but indicates there is a type mismatch:

cypress.config.ts:20:21 - error TS2322: Type 'import("/Users/.../Documents/.../.../node_modules/@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main").Plugin' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/.../Documents/.../.../node_modules/esbuild/lib/main").Plugin'.
Types of property 'setup' are incompatible.

etc etc...
I'm using the following versions:
  "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^19.2.0",
  "@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor": "^2.2.0",
  "cypress": "^13.1.0",

Where is this documented?

Does it not declare a peer dependency?

A minimal working example for your choice of configuration is given here https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/tree/v19.2.0/examples/esbuild-ts.
With your specified versions it works. Most likely the problem lies in tsconfig.json, make sure these two options are present
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "nodenext"
  }
}

Everything else is as you describe.
